# Need help to organise my Vuejs project architecture

Tags: javascript, vue.js, architecture, nuxt.js

This is not a technical question, it is more architecture/structure issue I'm facing and it would be nice to hear more opinions until I find the best solution to my problem.

Currently my project has:

- A big Vuejs project that wrap many micro front-end applications with separate vuejs instances.
- A Separate Nuxt application.
- A Java Backend/API project with some views embedding the nuxt application and the micro front-end applications. This application has the header with a menu to move through different pages that load the micro front-ends inside.

As you can imagine, this is a very old project that scaled up to be a huge mess and now I would like to find the best solution to restructure everything.

The main idea is to convert the Java project to be only an API and create a Front-End project to host the micro vuejs applications.

Now I would like to know your opinions on how to structure the front-end.

Actually my ideas are:

1. Since the Nuxt application is the newer, I was wondering to move all the micro applications inside it. Pro: I would have only one project to manage. Cons: I would lost the modularity of the micro front-ends.
2. Export the Micro front-end and try to import it inside Nuxt (I don't know about the real possibility to achieve this result).
3. Create a Node.js wrapper application (with the menu, etc...) to host all the micro front-ends. This would be pretty much similar to the current solution but maybe I would clean up everything.

One thing to consider is that all micro front-ends has their own Vuex Store.

I would really appreciate any kind of help, opinion, solution, etc... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the front end your right, maintaining one project is way more easier.
I think you can achieve doing 1 project AND keeping the modularity/

We tend to organize our code in monolitic way like this

```
app
    components
    store
    views
    ...
```

but you can also organize your code by feature

```
app
    components (global components used everywhere in the app)
    store (root state)
    views (base architecture)
    ...

    feature1
        components
        store
        views

    feature2
        components
        store
        views
```

vuex allow the store to be splitted in multiple modules
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html so each feature can keep it's own store

For the server part, it's a good idea to make your JAVA app API only. I tend to think that mixing front and back in a same project is less maintainable .
In a second time (if you wish) you can host your nuxt app on a node server and do SSR